# Link tag, <a href ="ipaddress"></a> does not open an external IP address

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, jupyterhub

I have this simple HTML file with a link tag that has an IP address as an address(the address is changed for security reasons). The IP address is the address of my JupyterHub server's HTTP proxy.

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href="http://22.222.22.20/" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But this link tag takes me nowhere it does not even open a new tab, however, if I put "https.://www.google.com" it open google. what is the solution?

Comment: where did you try it? can you point to the sandbox environment?

Comment: the external address is the address of my jupyterhub server's http proxy, the confusing part is it does not even open a new tab

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your HTML. If I enter `http://142.250.138.104/` into my address bar, I get google.com, so the syntax of protocol + IP seems to be correct. Are you sure that your server is actually listening for requests and responding?

Comment: First developer rule: check your console for errors. You surely are running inside a context (iframe) where "allow-popups" is not allowed, like the example I've created using the snippet tool. Second developer rule in StackOverflow: use the snippet tool to reproduce the problem xD https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Josh Yes the server responds to requests, if I directly open the URL in the browser it opens, but cant do that with link tag.

Comment: maybe you should add the port to the URL  `href="http://22.222.22.20:<port>/"`